# Importing jar in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, selenium, jar

I am currently working on an app in Android Studios, and am just getting to setting up my dependencies to other jars. I have working code doing exactly what it's supposed to do outside of the app project, I'm just having trouble integrating it. specifically, the selenium server standalone jar. Whenever I attempt to import it for some reason, the build fails, showing me this:

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
```

I know the jar works, and I know it's possible to include jars in Android Studio. I've successfully included Jsoup already, it just seems that something about selenium is throwing it off. I'm doing everything standard, I've put the jar in libs, and added a compile files() call in my manifest.If anyone could shed some light on this it would immensely ease my sorrows.

Comment: Try this: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/35343238/5475941][1]. I explained different approaches for importing JAR files into Android studio. I hope it helps.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35343238/5475941